# Where is the gnome option to display icons in menus?

Tags: gnome, menu, appearance, interface

I used to go to "System >> Preferences >> Appearance >> Interface", but I can't find that tab on Lucid or Maverick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gconf key is /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_have_icons.

*Note: I don't particularly endorse setting it to "True" in the long run. See [Andreas Nilsson's post](http://www.andreasn.se/blog/?p=103) and the discussion in [the related bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=557469) for the rationale behind setting it to "False" by default.*

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Why you don't endorse that?

Comment: I've edited my post include links to relevant discussion. Basically, determining which items should have icons should be a per-application design task to be guided by a set of guidelines; not something to be handled with a global variable.

Comment: Thanks. There must be an issue with Firefox on Gnome then, because it doesn't show my extension icons by default. I have helped many users with similar problems before, but I thought it was a Gnome settings issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Ubuntu Tweak. They have an option for that, among many other things. It also allows you to put icons in buttons.